# How to read empty cell from the web table

Tags: java, arrays, list, selenium-webdriver

How to read empty cell from the web table while iterating through each row to get the other data

HTML is as follows :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to print the values of the table cells from 1 to 7.
I am able to print all the values successfully , however I am stuck at reading empty cells from the web table and the code throws me "WebElement not found exception "

Code I have written :

```
List cols= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//tr//td[1]"));
System.out.println("No of columns are : " + cols.size());
WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));

for(int i=1;i<=cols.size();i++) {
for(int j=1;j<=3;j++) {

WebElement tableRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[" + i + "]//td[" + j + "]"));    

String rowtext = tableRow.getText();
System.out.println("text in the row of table : "+rowtext);

}
```

When it comes to

```
//tbody//tr[3]//td[3]
```

and

```
//tbody//tr[5]//td[2]
```

and

```
//tbody//tr[5]//td[3]

Exception - WebElementNotFound is thrown
```

How can I featch empty cell values is my quesy.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks,

Comment: Try to start iterating from 0 not 1

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I got the expected result using List and findelements.           for(int i=1;i<=cols.size();i++) {
     for(int j=1;j<=3;j++) {
    List<WebElement> allElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[" + i + "]//td[" + j + "]"));

    for(WebElement ele :allElements) {
     if (allElements!=null) {
        System.out.println("Row text is"+ele.getText());
     }
       
    }